# MySQL selecting names of customer with most purchase

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables connected with each other in the image

[![Image1][1]][1]

[image: Image2]

I have tried writing query

```
SELECT lastname,firstname
FROM customer,purchase_order
where customer.customer_id=purchase_order.customer_id
```

What parameter should I consider for most purchase?

Comment: A join is required to link multiple tables, try to look [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: What is the query you are supposed to modify?

Comment: What parameter should I consider for most purchase? Any idea?

Comment: There is no query to modify, we have to write a query

Comment: Well, your screenshot says "Modify the query to select ..."

Comment: Thats is a mistake, there is no query

Comment: Check out HAVING and COUNT at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp, for example, and query table PURCHASE_ORDER.

Comment: Consider the number of orders for customer. So you have to `count()` foreach customer

Comment: Do you mean order id?

Comment: Yes, you can `count(order_id)` but important is `group by`, look @chessweb's link

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that by adjusting the select clause (remove order_id).
Then you will need a HAVING clause to implement the condition to only show the customers with the most purchase orders.

Comment: But what parameter  should I consider for most purchase?

Comment: the max count of purchase order

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lastname,firstname
FROM customer
INNER JOIN purchase_order
ON customer.customer_id=purchase_order.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(order_id) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain why this code helps and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
select lastname, firstname from customer c
inner join (
select customer_id, count(1) from purchase_order
group by 1
order by 2 desc limit 1) most 
/* the above sub-query named as 'most' fetched the customer id with the maximum 
number of orders */
on c.customer_id = most.customer_id; -- this is a simple join of customers table with the table generated from sub-query above
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain why this code helps and what it does.

Comment: Hi @BDL , I have added some comments explaining my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.firstname,c.lastname
FROM customer c
JOIN purchase_order po
ON c.customer_id = po.customer_id
GROUP BY c.firstname,c.lastname
ORDER BY COUNT(po.order_id) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?